# In r studio when using mutate() in combination with c_across() all rows are returning the same value

Tags: r, dplyr

I am fairly new to r and am working with a large, spectral data set. I am wanting to average red and NIR wavelegnths' reflectance for each sample. Using pivot_wider I have wavelengths 350-2500 displayed as columns containing reflectance. I tried (using dplyr):

```
df%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=Wavelength,values_from=Reflectance,names_prefix="W")%>%
  mutate(red=(mean(c_across(W600:W700))))%>%
  mutate(nir=(mean(c_across(W720:W1300))))
```

When I did this, the same value was returned for each sample in the new columns, which is incorrect. There was no error message. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you please share: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `rowwise`

```
df%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=Wavelength,values_from=Reflectance,names_prefix="W")%>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    red=mean(c_across(W600:W700)),
    nir=mean(c_across(W720:W1300))
  )
```

Comment: that solved the issue, thank you!